# How to force update after dom change with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a component that renders an svg path and want an other component to render at the bottom of that path. The path component looks like this. Where {d} comes from an array that is converted to something like 'M0,0,L100,120,L0,240'.

```
<svg>
  <path
    ref={pathRef}
    d={d}
    ...
  >
  </path>
</svg>
```

I have a method to add a point to that path. And after the path is rendered (the height of the domNode changes) I want the other component to be rendered at the bottom.

Within the parent I use useEffect() to get pathRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

But no matter what I do I always get the old state's height. The final dom change doesn't seem to trigger an update in my component.

What am I missing? I tried useLayoutEffect(), I even tried to console.log the current height outside of any useEffect but I never get the latest value.

Comment: I can't comment so i am asking it here. Are you updating the state after retrieving it in the useEffect hook?

Comment: can you show your useEffect? you might need to add d as dependency to useEffect

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, try to use an `useState` in combination with `useCallback` hooks. Like:

```
const [, updateComponent] = React.useState();
const forceUpdateComponent = React.useCallback(() => updateComponent({}), []);
```

Then, when you need a re-render just call `forceUpdateComponent()`.

Comment: But how do I check for the moment to forceUpdateComponent()? After all updates are done I still have an old value to make any comparison.

Comment: You could try in the same method that add point to path.

Comment: No like I explained to @Davia